# wp-json how to fetch image link?

Tags: json

i'm trying to fetch some data and images. everything is working good, but i'm really tired to fetch the post thumbnail image.

```
$data = array(
        ':attachment' => $record['_links']['wp:attachment'][0]['href'],
    );
```

the above code fetching media link such as `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=273138` but i want to fetch like that `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/nigeria-killing-20-dead.jpg` how i can do that? please try with a wordpress website with wp-json to see the structure.

Comment: How does the current code fetch the media? Where is `$record` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already fix this by using this

```
$data = array(
        ':attachment' => $record[_embedded]['wp:featuredmedia']['0'][source_url]
    );
```

thanks for no person answered my question.

Comment: Welcome to wpse! theres no need for that. It can happen that some questions will not get answered, and its ok, not everyone knows/understands the issue or how to solve it. What important is that you have found a solution to your problem. In the future consider adding as much relevant information as possible about your question, that way more people could understand it and help you out. Also, answering your own question is a good thing, that way you can help others that encounter the same problem solve it, your own answer could someday help someone out, and thats a good thing!

Comment: You probably want `'source_url'` in quotes.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast yes you are right. thanks.